# Paste from Clipboard in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is there a method to paste from the clipboard in Google Sheets? I recorded a macro that includes a "paste" but when I looked at the script the "paste" function hard coded the values. I looked through the documentation but could not find anything like paste from clipboard values.

Comment: Apps Script executes on Google's servers, not in your browser. There is no guarantee that a browser is even open when an Apps Script function executes. So no, there is no way to create a macro that reads from your browser or os clipboard.

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks.